What are the practical insights into the real world that probability values provide?
Mathematical probability space is based on 3 assumptions, (e.g., a function that is summed up to 1, or to 100%). We don't argue that the claims (assumptions) occur, but rather we say that if they occur, so that and that.
Hence, the probability doesn't "exists" in the real world and there is no function running at some location in the world which is a probability function. It is a  model of some phenomena in the world. Indeed the mathematical model of probability function provides some insights into the real world. The question is what insights?
The question is what does it mean when we say that the odds for Trump to be elected are 50%? Or what does it mean when we say that the odds for the dice to present 4 is 1/6?
The meaning is that in a model that we term "probability", (roughly put), the output of the probability function for the input of the scenario that the dice will show 4, is 1/6. But yet this is not the only thing we can derive from the statement. There are additional practical insights from that statement. For example, no rational person will bet in bets agency for some scenario with odds of 0%. My point is that there are additional insights beside the one I mentioned. What are these additional insights?

There is a more important side to the science of probability. It points to the most important question about our reality. Is it natural (physical), and as such, mathematically random? Or is it partially or completely artificial (a work of God or the computer simulator's architect)? As with many other important questions, it will probably never be answered with certainty. But we don't need Yes or No. We use probability as a hint, a clue if you want. It shows us the degree to which our perception of reality leans toward (God or no God).

In a single trial, the probability of a given outcome may not be all that meaningful. In a million trials, however, probabilities can be a prudent basis for planning. The insurance industry, for example, is based on probabilities.

I can half-remember a humorous quote about interpretations of probability. It goes something like this:
What does it mean when the weather forecast says there is a 60% chance of rain today?

In Berlin they think it means that the weather forecaster believes it will rain today but there is only a 60% probability that they are correct.

In Paris they think it means that 60% of the people working at the meteorological office think it will rain today.

In London they think it means that 60% of Londoners will get rained on today.

In New York it means you can go into a bar and someone will offer you 3:2 odds that it will rain today.



The point is that there are different interpretations of probability. The 2024 US presidential election is not a repeatable event, so it cannot have a frequency. Also there is no obvious geometrical symmetry to it.
The probability of an election outcome could be a prediction based on a stochastic model incorporating known data. Or it could just be a degree of credence held by a rational agent.
A simple model of human decision making consists in supposing that people are guided by beliefs and desires. Beliefs can be thought of as degrees of credence in various possible events. Desires can be thought of as assignments of utility to those events. A rational decision is one that uses some strategy such as maximising expected utility. It is a highly oversimplified model, but the basic idea is that beliefs are action-guiding, so the degree of credence that a person attaches to an event is important to their decisions.
So the 'practical insights' that you mention are that a person who believes in a 60% chance of rain will take their umbrella with them and will not accept a bet on rain at odds of evens.

+1 And the OP should be aware that the psychological application of statistics and probability is quite often not only subject to a plurality of interpretations,  but that it is just downright abused to convey certainty and authority unjustifiably as in false precision. Thus the role of the philosopher of math is to disabuse us of claims of the abusive mathematician.

If the only practical insight is how people act given a probability value then how is it different from following a horoscope? The question is why it is rational for people to take umbrellas and bet on odds, if it is, what it is in the real world that probability picks out to make it so, if anything. I can see the answer for 'repeatable' events with stable frequencies, one will be better off in a long run when acting on odds consistently. But weather and elections are not 'repeatable'. What about them, on whatever interpretation of probability? SEP article is also lacking on this point.

@Conifold Bayesianism doesn't try to tell you what probabilities it is rational to believe, only how it is rational to update them. In some cases you may also be able to form objective priors based on maximum entropy or some similar criterion. But rational or not, an agency announcing that the probability of a Trump victory is 0.5 just means that is the prediction yielded by their stochastic model. You are always at liberty to criticise the reliability of their model...

Constructing a reliable model is not that different from the familiar problem of attempting to construct general theories from a finite number of particular observations. Though of course stochastic theories are harder to falsify than deterministic ones.

@Bumble Would it be right to infer that your use of 'stochastic theory' essentially translates to 'statistical model of a semi-random physical phenomenon'?

If I go outside with an umbrella because I believe it will rain, where does credence play a role here? I don’t attach a number to this belief consciously, so what makes you think this is happening unconsciously? And if you think it’s not happening at all, what is the point of this concept? You haven’t answered this

@Bumble “Constructing a reliable model is not that different from the familiar problem of attempting to construct general theories from a finite number of particular observations.” It’s miles and leagues different. In a scientific theory, you have an explanation for why a certain thing happens. You have no such explanation for a “stochastic theory”. There is no explanation for why an atom decays at time t instead of t + 1. That’s not a theory

So Bayesianism has to be supplemented by something else, what is it? Reliability is not the issue, the missing part makes it unclear what "prediction of a stochastic model" even means for non-'repeatable' events. We can test probabilities in QM because we can repeat setups and tally the outcomes, we cannot do it for Trump or weather. I am guessing one presupposes some sort of analysis of complex events into basic constituents that are 'repeatable' and probabilities are made sense of as of compounds of those. But I have not seen it spelled out and justified in interpretations of probability.

@JD I expect that means the same or similar, though the physical phenomenon itself does not have to be random. It could be chaotic. Or it could be just that we are modelling our best understanding of a complex system and we are using epistemic probabilities to allow for our lack of knowledge.

@Syed If you take an umbrella when you go out it is because you have some credence that it will rain. If you were certain that it will not rain you wouldn't bother with the umbrella. Whether the decision process is conscious or not and whether you put numbers to it or not is irrelevant. The whole point of decision theory is to put numbers to our degree of credence and our utility. We have to make decisions with uncertain and incomplete information and we make better decisions when we can quantify those things.

Also I strongly disagree that stochastic theories are fundamentally different. We can explain radioactive decay. It is an example of quantum tunnelling. But our best theories about it are stochastic and not deterministic. That does not mean they are not theories. All the non-trivial predictions of quantum mechanics are probabilistic and not deterministic. We would hardly say that quantum mechanics does not qualify to be called a theory because it does not make deterministic predictions.

@Conifold Defenders of objective Bayesianism usually speak of calibration and equivocation. Calibration means your credences must align with known frequencies. Equivocation means your priors should make the least possible assumptions about the information you possess. This is where maximum entropy and Kullback-Leibler divergence come in: they can be thought of as highly generalised forms of the principle of indifference.

As to how we construct stochastic models: in a similar way that we construct deterministic ones. By finding all the variables, identifying the fundamental elements, and doing our best to understand the dependencies and relationships between them. We can't perform controlled experiments on the weather and we can't repeat an election. But many sciences are observational, e.g. geology and astronomy. That doesn't stop us making theories. We have theories of stellar evolution, but they are probabilistic and the evolution of any given star is unrepeatable.

@Bumble You just asserted your conclusions again. Your argument is circular. I pointed out that when we make a decision to use an umbrella, there seems to be no conscious or unconscious process requiring credences or numbers. You then responded to this by saying “the whole point of decision theory is to put numbers to our degree of credence.” You have not provided any argument as to why we should use the concept of a degree of credence in the first place

secondly, the part of quantum mechanics that we can actually outline are the deterministic parts of it, such as Schrodinger’s equation. We have no explanation for why an atom decays a time t instead of t + 1. A stochastic prediction isn’t a prediction and is unfalsifiable. If you tell me that an atom has 90% chance of decaying in a certain period, it doesn’t tell you whether it will decay. If it decays, you can say “there was a 90% chance. Makes sense” If it doesn’t, you can say “see, there was a 10% chance.”

@Syed The point of decision theory is not to describe our mental processes but to provide a theory of what constitutes good decision making. All the standard forms of decision theory use probabilities and utilities. I do not need to argue why we should use degrees of credence, I am pointing out that decision theory does so and it is a well established field of study.

Quantum mechanics is a theory and it makes probabilistic predictions. It does not fail to be a theory for that reason. Its predictions are testable in the same way that those of any statistical theory are. What do you suppose statistical hypothesis testing is about? Lots of theories provide probabilistic predictions. Econometrics, epidemiology, weather forecasting, climate modelling, business analytics, reliability engineering, financial modelling, risk analysis, bioinformatics, the list is almost endless.

@Bumble The tests aren’t actually based on probability though. When we test things in QM, we are testing frequency related facts which have no notion of credence or probability. We are testing, for example, how many atoms decay in a certain period.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For dice, a simple frequentist interpretation is pretty intuitive (i.e. if we rolled these dice in the same fashion 1 million times what would the distribution of numbers be?)
For the election, the problem is somewhat more complicated, because humans aren't dice, but it's essentially the same.  The probability, though, is not over candidates so much as it's over VOTERS.
Some time before the election, we can go out and ask people who they will vote for, and hopefully they will be more-or-less truthful (there is some accounting for nuance here in models).  Based on this assumption, we literally go out and ask people who they will vote for.  IF we could ask EVERYONE, then we could make statements like "so-and-so will win the election".  However, asking everyone is prohibitive, so we take a sample of people instead.  This sample is usually chosen carefully to be "representative" of the population demographics.  Based on this sample, we can start to make frequentist-style statements about the people we didn't sample, in the same way we do with the dice.
To illustrate, let's mix up the dice example just slightly.  Instead of having a nice fair die, we have a loaded die.  In other words, the die will come up 1,2,3,4,5 or 6, but not necessarily with equal probability.  How could we determine these probabilities?  One way is to use our intuition from the fair die:  If we actually roll this die 1 million times, and tabulate the results, we can use this info to estimate the probabilities of each possible outcome, and from this we can make forecasts about future rolls.  Say, if the die came up 1 100,000 out of our million rolls, and we plan to make another million rolls, we would expect a 1 ~100,000 times +- some comparatively small error.
This is what we do with the election.  We pretend that voters are so many dice, and their demographics and other variables inform how they are loaded.  We then ask voters who they will vote for, and use this info to extrapolate to other voters.  As an overly simple analogy, if we ask 1 million voters who they will vote for, and 600,000 say "Alice", then we might expect another million voters to come up ~600,000 +-error as "Alice", and we might expect 150 million voters to vote "Alice" at approximately 60%.
This error is actually important, and is quantifiable.  The quantitication is not a trivial exercise, and I cannot possibly do the topic justice here.  You can get a cursory treatment of the problem as applies to dice in an intro statistics class.  Even with dice we need to talk about probabilities over experiments (i.e. if we roll our die a million times, a million times, what happens?).  The human element adds untold complexity for which adjustments, assumptions and approximations abound. Such is sociological research /shrug.
SO, now, imagine that the error was 0.  We could extrapolate perfectly from our 1 million strong sample and say "Alice will win the election".  Since the error is not 0, Alice may or may not win the election.  This is where the obvious interpretation of probabilities comes in: it's not a probability of Alice winning that is foundational, it's a probability that a certain number of out-of-sample individuals vote for Alice, and there is a direct frequentist analogy here to the dice problem.

Believing that there is probability p (expressed as a decimal; divide percentage by 100 for decimal probability) means that you believe that if you make n statistically independent bets of probability p you will win a number of times with an expectation value of np and a standard deviation equal to:
√(np(1-p))
Betting odds b (expressed as a decimal) means that the person or institution you are betting against is willing to pay out 1/b dollars for every 1 dollar you bet if you win. (So if you give the institution $100 at 50% odds, and you win, you get $200 back for a net gain of $100.) This means that the person or institution you are betting against thinks that the probability p of you winning is less than b.
See: binomial distribution.

You can't make n independent bets on a single event like an election. Can you expand on how this applies?

@barmar you can make n statistically independent bets on n statistically independent events that you think have the same probability. The only thing that needs to be the same about them is what you think the probability of winning is. In fact, not even that. You can expand the definition to winning a number of times equal to the sum over n events with index i of p_i, and a standard deviation equal to the square root of the sum over n events with index index i of p_i(1-p_i)

Yes, that's what I was thinking of. E.g. there are odds on every presidential election, so you can use that to establish your expectation of winnings if you bet each time. I was trying to suggest that you add this detail to your answer.

Someone asserts

The probability of A (some particular person) winning this election is 50%.

This is considered to be equivalent to saying

The odds of A winning this election are equal to the odds of A not winning this election.

The question is what does it mean to make that statement. We're not interested in the meaning of "winning" or "election", so we can simplify and generalize the statement to

The odds of X happening (X refers to some event) are equal to the odds of X not happening.

which is considered equivalent to any of the following statements

The odds of X happening are 1:1 (read as 'one to one').
The probability of X happening is 0.5.
The chance that X happens is equal to the chance that X doesn't happen.
It's equally likely that X happens and that X does not happen.

Several ways to explain what that means are:

If X happens, I (the speaker of the original statement) will be just as surprised as when X does not happen.


I'm just as certain (or uncertain) that X will happen than I am that X will not happen.

In terms of a betting scenario, it can be explained as

If I'm forced (or willing) to bet (for any amount) and write down my prediction of what will happen (or what has happened, if I don't know this yet), having to write down "A" to indicate my bet on X (X happening) and "B" to indicate that I bet on not X (X not happening), then after I've handed my bet to a bookie, it's perfectly fine with me if the bookie, before inspecting my written bet, decides to interpret "A" as a bet on X not happening and "B" as a bet on X.

Or simply

If I'm forced to bet, I'd be just as willing to bet on X as on not X.

In other words, in a betting scenario, believing in equal odds is equivalent to being indifferent as to the interpretation of the bet, allowing the bookie to swap the accepted bet. (This is, of course, under the assumption that the bookie has not first looked at the actual content of one's prediction. But if the bookie also has no knowledge about X yet, then that assumption could be dropped. The assumption is just made in order to prevent cheating; a bookie that already knows the outcome, X or not X, would have an unfair advantage over the bettor.)
I believe the above hits the core 'meaning' of "equal odds". However, there is a bit more going on in the initial statement. In particular it uses the word "equal", it assigns a numerical value (0.5) to a "probability", it assigns a numerical value (1 expressed as fraction) to the odds. So, there is an implicit assumption that a feeling of (un)certainty or an attitude of indifference can we translated into a numerical measure. There is a reason for wanting to do this, and it is justified (at least I don't know of anyone who doesn't think it is, and the justification can be spelled out.) But the justification is tied up with a notion of rational decision making. "Rational" in this context is not a very mysterious, philosophical concept. A rational decision is just a decision that leads to the most preferred outcome (or to an outcome that is not less preferred than any other), given the circumstances. (Most preferred, meaning most preferred by the decision maker.) For a general, not too long, but opinionated overview of some of the philosophical issues, see for instance The Philosophy of Statistics, 2000, by D.V. Lindley which summarizes, in a way, his transition from a frequentist to a Bayesian and finally to a subjectivist interpretation.

First, regarding terminology, odds are typically expressed as ratios, not percentages. But there is a direct relationship between odds and a probability of a given outcome, so your question is still easily understood.
When someone expresses that the probability of a given candidate winning an election is 50% it can mean:

a Bayesian probability statement; or
an empirical statement about how frequently a candidate won among a sample of simulated election outcomes based on existing polling information and other modelling assumption


Even when your question probably does not aim at the following insight into the fundamental role of probability in explaining reality:

According to quantum theory  Erwin Schroedinger’s wave equation
determines the time development of the psi-function of a quantum
system, hence the whole dynamics of non-relativistic quantum
mechanics.
According to Max Born the squared modulus of its psi-function is the
probability to obtain specific results when interacting with a
physical system.
In this sense, the time development of probability functions
determines the dynamics of the real world: The interaction of
quantum systems generates the transition from the quantum world of
possibilities to the real world of facts.


Probability is a model aiming to adequately reflecting certainty of events.
Need to say, probability is a model aiming to do so, and it's possible that some other model that one can suggest could better reflect a measure of certainty to one's needs.
When the weatherperson says that probability of rain is X, what one should understand is, that the certainty of the event of rain, proposed by a (commonly-accepted-but-yet-)arbitrary model which we term "probability" (or "statistics"), is the numeric value X.
One could accept that certainty value or reject it (in case that the model of "probability" is not adequate/precise to one's needs).

Probability is a mental construct and more of a concept that summarizes things and doesn’t actually have anything to say about how the world works.
It is a descriptor of the world, not an explainer. This is the crucial difference. Once you understand this, things become more clear. The problem is that in society, there seems to be a consensus that probability is something more than just a summarizing term. This consensus is wrong, and I can explain why.
When we say that the dice will roll on 3 and that has a 1/6 probability, we mean that if we rolled it tons of times, approximately 1/6 of the time it would land on 3. This is merely a frequency related fact. We just use the term probability to summarize this fact.
But in the examples you mentioned, probability is being mistakenly used as some sort of mythological tool that will help you know what will happen. There is no true meaning to the idea that Trump has a 60% chance of winning the election. He will either win or won’t. All it can mean, and did mean, is that 60% of people think Trump will win, and 40% of people think he won’t. This is, again, a frequency related fact that the notion of probability just neatly summarizes.
In summary, probability is only meaningful when summarizing a frequency oriented fact. Otherwise, it is meaningless

Downvoted. Your answer succeeds in being completely wrong, which is quite an achievement.

@Bumble Are you going to try to show what’s incorrect or just assert your conclusions like Bayesians do?

OK. The first is paragraph is incorrect. There are lots of statistical theories that have things to say about how the world works. Econometrics, epidemiology, weather forecasting, climate modelling, business analytics, reliability engineering, financial modelling, risk analysis, bioinformatics, the list is almost endless. The second paragraph is incorrect. Probability and statistics are used for more than just summarising data: the entire field of inferential statistics is concerned with drawing inferences and making predictions.

The third paragraph is partly correct. The frequency theory of probability identifies a probability with the frequency of an indefinitely long run of trials. A probability is not a summary of an observed frequency.

The fourth paragraph is complete nonsense. Single events can have probabilities. The fact that frequentism has difficulty explaining how just shows up the limitations of frequentism. You can go into a betting shop and ask for odds that Trump will win and odds are interconvertible with probabilities. Objective Bayesians maintain that there is an ideal model of rational belief revision that can be described using probability theory. This is not merely asserted but is argued for, e.g. Jon Williamson, In Defence of Objective Bayesianism, Oxford, 2010.

Trump having a 60% probability of winning has nothing to do with what proportion of people think he will win. That is irrelevant. It is a prediction from a theoretical model. The model might include some data about voting intentions but it has nothing to do with how many people think Trump will win. It is not summarising anything; it is predicting. Of course Trump will win or he won't, but since we don't know in advance we can assign a probability to it.

The final paragraph is incorrect. Frequencies are useful data with which to calibrate probabilities but probabilities are not defined by frequencies. Probabilities are better understood as a way of quantifying uncertainty. This approach to probability and statistics is argued for very well in Dennis Lindley's book, Understanding Uncertainty, Wiley, 2014.
